# Como hacer diseño responsive usando la plantilla WebApplication .NET Framework con un menú grande

Tags: c#, aplicación-web, responsive

Cuando utilizo la platilla WebApplication de .NET Framework MVC y añado más puntos de menú y la autenticación primera (cuentas de usuario individuales) cuando ejecuto la aplicación en una tablet se me monta el menú (fondo negro) encima del primer texto (Contact por ejemplo).

He intentado hacer los div flotantes (float: left) pero el comportamiento no es el esperado. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? No quiero sacrificar el texto del título de la página.

**Código _Layout.cshtml**

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            < ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                < li>@Html.ActionLink("Inicio", "Index", "Home")</li>
                < li>@Html.ActionLink("Acerca de", "About", "Home")</li>
                < li>@Html.ActionLink("Contacto", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                < li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu 1", "Menu1", "Home")</li>
                < li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu 2", "Menu2", "Home")</li>
                < li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu 3", "Menu3", "Home")</li>
            < /ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial") </div>
```

**Código Contact.cshtml**

```
<h2></h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
```

Pues cuando voy reduciendo la pantalla del navegador hasta adaptarla a una resolución de tablet el texto `< h2 >@ViewBag.Title.< /h2>` que sería de "Contact" queda tapado por le menú superior.